# how to get results from mFusedLocationProviderClient (Task<Location> not running??)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fusedlocationproviderclient

I am new to Android development, and I am making a map app where you have to get the user's current location. I am currently using a FusedLocationProviderClient as the docs say to use. Every time that I add an on complete listener, and run the code, the task never completes! Is there something about android or Java in general that I have not learned yet?

I guess what I am trying to ask is why does it just skip over the addOnCompleteListener as if the task isn't even running? I am not very familiar with Tasks, so I tried to do a little research, but didn't find anything helpful.

I have tried to check if it is successful, by adding:

```
//This loops Infinitely (I tested for 5 mins)
while(!tLocation.isSuccessful())
{
     System.out.println(tLocation.isComplete()); //This returns false
     System.out.println(tLocation.isCancelled()); //This also returns false
}
```

But then it just freezes the app, and it never gets done!

Here is a code sample from my project (I call this method to get the Location):

```
private Location tempLocation; //Where I want to save the Location
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;

public void getUserLocation() {
        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        if(mLocationPermissionGranted)
        {
            try {
                final Task<Location> tLocation = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();

                tLocation.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Location location = tLocation.getResult();
                            tempLocation = location;
                        }
                    }
                });

            }catch (SecurityException e) {
                Toast.makeText(OtechLocation.getContext(), "Unable to find Location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
        } else
        {
            Toast.makeText(OtechLocation.getContext(), "Enable Location Services to activate feature", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

If you need anything clarified, then just let me know! Thanks in advance!